# Date Conversion from value in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, date, date-format

Does anyone possibly recognize the following value "40195.315752" as a date?  I need to convert/format this value-based date to a System.DateTime object, but don't understand it's format.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know what that specific value is meant to represent? Perhaps it's "days since the midnight 1900 January 1st UTC"?

Comment: Hi. Can you share the source of this value? May be that could assist us a bit.

Comment: Where u find this time format?

Comment: Thank you for all of your help.  The long-value represents the date an album was added to a jukebox application and comes from the database of Albums the jukebox player uses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a `serial date-time`, which means it's the number of days since a particular date. Note that you need to know the date which it is an offset to. In Excel, that would be Jan 1st, 1900, which makes your date `17/01/2010  07:34:41`, but other programs will vary.

Another common start date is 1st January 1970 (Unix Epoch).

Answer (score 3):

enjoy it:

```
DateTime.FromOADate(40195.315752).ToLongDateString()
```

and to convert it to DateTime

```
DateTime MyDateTime = DateTime.FromOADate(40195.315752);
```

It means `Sunday,January 17 2010`

Answer (score 0):

That would possibly be the number of days since a certain date (possibly january 1st 1900), before the decimal point?

Answer (score 0):

the value you have displayed is a double...

```
var val = 40195.315752;
            var span = System.TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(val);
            var time = new DateTime(span.Ticks);
```

above will convert it to Datetime but besure to note that System.Timespan continas several overloads to load span you need to identify which one is that you want...